# Let $f:[0,2]\to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function with no roots. Prove that the function is not surjective and $f(0)\cdot f(2)>0$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functions, continuity

Let $f:[0,2]\to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function with no roots

i) Prove that the function is not surjective

ii) Show that $f(0)\cdot f(2)>0$

Got no ideas, maybe $y=f(x)$? Doesn't seem helpful though.

Also, is it possible to change the interval from $[0, 2]$ to $[a, b]$? I remember asking about a problem here for a particular 'case' and it ended up being true for every 'case': [How to prove the following integral equation? $\int_{0}^{c}x^2f(x)=0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4115161/how-to-prove-the-following-integral-equation-int-0cx2fx-0) (hope it makes sense what I'm saying)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I suspect some mis-copying. I'm suspicious of i) since it would be true without the condition that $f$ has no roots. In ii) is it really $f(0)\cdot (2)$ or is it $f(0)\cdot f(2)$? Neither makes a ton of sense since $f(x)=0.5$ is a counterexample to either form of it.

Comment: Found it on a discord server. It's just this exercise from a book (don't know what book)
It is $f(0)\cdot f(2)$

Comment: Maybe it should be $f(0)\cdot f(2)>\color{red}{0}$? (due to continuity the function is either positive or negative on $[0,2]$)

Comment: Damn, didn't realise I forgot to put the f before 2. my bad
Jesus I also put > 2 instead of > 0.. thanks for the heads up @projectilemotion

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Since it has no roots there is no $x \in [0,2]$ such that $f(x) = 0 \in \mathbb R$
2. (*Updated*) Assume $f(0)\cdot f(2) \le 0$, but this implies either at least one of $f(0)$ or $f(2)$ is $0$ (contradiction) or they have different signs which means there is a zero between $0$ and $2$ (contradiction). Therefore $f(0)\cdot f(2) > 0$.

Answer (score 1):

If there are no roots the graph of f does not cross the x- Axis.
So either the graph is always below or above the x-Axis
so,can't be surjective and ii) should be obviuous now

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer :

1. Are there solutions to $f(x) = 0$ ? What does it entail vis à vis surjectivity ?
2. What does $f(0).(2)$ mean ?

Comment: I think he meant $f(0)\cdot f(2)$

Answer (score -1):

i) $f^{-1}(0) = \emptyset$.

ii) Is not true, consider $f \equiv 1$.